# How long does it take to complete a partial and full flap overspeed inspection?

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps

I am trying to determine the cost of a flap overspeed inspection. Ignoring the cost of any parts. On average, how long does a flap overspeed inspection take? Or how long would a partial/full flap overspeed inspection take?

Comment: On an A380? Cub? Citation?

Comment: Small business jet lets say the size of a citation.

Answer (score 4):

On a regional jet size airplane, about 1-2 manhours. On a large airliner, maybe one guy on each wing would take 1-2 hours, so say 4 manhours.

You're just inspecting for things that are bent or broken.

If the inspection procedure requires removal of fairings and panels, maybe add another hour.